# Obtener la IP del cliente en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ip

Necesito obtener la direccion IP de quien consuma el API en el que estoy trabajando este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
app.post('/api/v1',(req,res) =>{
  ConnectTelnet();

  var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;


console.log(ip);
})
```

Pero el resultado que me imprime es este: **"::1"**

Alguien sabe por que y como solucionarlo?

Gracias

Comment: Prueba con request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] (Por si hay proxy)

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo resultado :(

Answer (score 5):

En localhost estas obteniendo '::1' porque estas utilizando IPv6 , podrías obtener '::1'(ipv6) o '127.0.0.1'(ipv4).

Trata de acceder a la url desde otro dispositivo.

En tu código verifica si tienes la configuración para 'trust proxy'. Por defecto esta en falso pero si tienes algo así:

```
app.set('trust proxy', true);
```

Quiere decir que esta activada, entonces para obtener la ip del cliente tendrías que hacer:

```
var ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

Puedes revisar la documentación de express de donde obtuve la información [aquí](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set), la información esta justamente en donde dice 'Options for `trust proxy` setting'